# FxCop appears to have hung or deadlocked : Possibility to ignore some Methods from check

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, fxcop

On some of your developer machines, we get the exception in the Title. There is a Thread about this here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/770502/vs2012-fxcop-ca0001-fxcop-appears-to-have-hung-or-deadlocked

My guess is, that this exception happens if we write large Queryables, which the FxCopy kindahow wants to compile, but then get's an timeout/memory error.

Ofc we can just suppress the warning, but this doesn't help, since to generate the warning, it's already to late.

Does anyone still have this exception, or is the a possibility to exclude methods from the FxCop, so we have a easier time finding out, which method is problematic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either a `.fxcop` project or the `/types` command line argument for `fxcopcmd.exe` to control the types the analysis targets.  However, this would be a potentially time-consuming approach for attempting to find the source of the problem.  You might want to try running `fxcopcmd.exe` with the `/verbose` switch first to see if you can get more information about the error or its context.  Failing that, attaching a debugger to the process might also help.

Comment: Thanks, funnily enought now it's working again, as soon as we get the error again, we will give it a try